# Using nested routing in Next to get data from Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I want to get data from Firestore in Next.JS like Reddit. For example (http://localhost:3000/r/BestBurger) in cloud firestore my data is in (/BestBurger/posts/posts/KrcvgXMX4HyNKPD1kRAR)

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';


import firebase from '../../firebase/clientApp';
import Card from '../../components/card/Card';
;




export default function Page() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { page } = router.query;

    function usePosts() {
        const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])



        useEffect(() => {
            firebase
                .firestore()
                .collection(`${page}`).doc('posts').collection('posts')
                .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
                    const newPosts = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => (
                        {
                            id: doc.id,
                            ...doc.data()
                        }))
                    setPosts(newPosts)
                }
                )
        }, [])

        return posts;
    }

    const posts = usePosts()
    console.log(posts)

    return (
        <>
            {
                posts.map((post) => (
                    <Card key={post.id}>
                        <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                        {post.body}
                    </Card>
                ))
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

Again, I want to get my page route to the .collection()

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `router.asPath` and extract what you need from it?

Comment: Please check `getServerSideProps`, `getStaticPaths`, `getStaticProps` in Next JS dynamic routes [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props). Also I have a similar [stackoverflow thread](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props), where OP is fetching the document with 'ctx.query.id' using getServerSideProps.

Comment: I need to know if you are still stuck with the issue. If yes, please provide me further details if the above comment was not helpful. If no, then please provide the solution by posting it as an answer so that it will be useful to community users.